# How to return a promise using web sockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket, promise

I have this function:

```
function authentification(jsonHeder: any): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');
        if (!jsonHeder.email || !jsonHeder.password) reject(new Error('bad request'));

        ws.onopen = async function() {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    command: '-userLogin',
                    instanceIdentifier: jsonHeder.email,
                    password: jsonHeder.password
                })
            );
        };

        ws.onmessage = async function(message) {
            const json = JSON.parse(message.data.toString());
            if (json.isError === false) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(new Error('bad request'));
            }
        }

    });
}
```

and I'm trying to get the approval for an authentification, and when I am trying to print the result I receive a Promise {  }.

the call function is like this:

```
const result = authentification(jsonHeder);
console.log('result: ', result);
```

and when I'm trying to put await operator I received a compile error. What can I do?

Comment: What error are you getting? You're probably using `await` outside of an `async` function

Comment: Unexpected token
, expected ";" (109:29)

  107 |
  108 |         const jsonHeder = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.headers));
> 109 |         const result = await authentification(jsonHeder);
      |                              ^
  110 |         console.log('result: ', result);
  111 |
  112 |         request

Comment: this is the error @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: I guess you are right... but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: That error is ocurring in a bit of code you're not showing, show the whole code.

Comment: It's a lot of code... can you give me any advice to solve the problem?

Comment: The advice is to look at the stack trace, and check the function where it's occurring. You should post the function where that's happening.

Comment: Thx a lot I found the error :)